# ROS Answers SE migration: QT and ROS

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have recently started using Qt for some basic GUI front end for my applications in ROS. I am currently using Qmake directly to perform the necessary operations with my ROS program.

I would like to know what is the benefit of using the Qt-ROS package over the normal Qt? Because I am currently developing my Qt app with the help of Qt creator and using terminal signals for various push buttons and other such operations.

Is there any benefit other than having Qt inside the ROS package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41525/qt-and-ros/) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though not a complete answer, here are some advantages of using `qt_create` pkg in `qt_ros` stack:

- Upon creating pkg, `CMakeLists.txt` will be modified, which allows you to build pkg (by `rosmake`) that uses `Qt` on the fly

  - MOC files will be generated automatically
  - include paths, library paths are filled.
  - `Qt`'s `resource` files will be integrated.
- A class automatically generated called `QNode` provides interface between `ROS` and your `Qt` codes.

Although `qt_create` is deprecated in `fuerte`(http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_create), it still works fine on my environment. HTH.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-09-06**:
Thanks for that bit of info. If you say qt_create is being deprecated from fuerte then is there any replacement for that for the fuerte and future releases? Because being at the starting point i really would not want to use a deprecated stack. Thanks

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-09-06**:
The stack is not getting depracated, just the tool which is moving to a [pypi package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=pkg_edit&name=roscreate). I haven't advertised that yet, because fuerte and qt_ros is in the middle of the ros catkin upgrade. Feel free to pip install that package though.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-09-06**:
Groovy will finally see qt_ros as a catkin package sitting alongside a create script coming from that pypi roscreate package.